# jq: Search for property by name deep inside unknown input structure and print the path

Tags: path, jq

The title says it all: A jq program takes an input JSON document whose structure I'm only vaguely familiar with, and I want it to print the path to all properties within it that have a certain name.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you want to find the paths to objects with a key named "b". One approach would be to use paths(objects) as illustrated here:

```
def data: {a:{b:1,c:{b:2}}};

data
| paths(objects | has("b") )
```

Or slightly more efficiently:

```
data
| paths
| select( .[-1] == "b" )
| .[:-1]
```

Invocation: jq -n -c -f program.jq

Output:

```
["a"]
["a","c"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Older question here, but this very much my typical use case.

For a solution for this specific type of problem see:
https://github.com/TomConlin/json_to_paths

usage  e.g.
`json2jqpath.jq file.json | grep "certain_name"`

Basically reduces an arbitrary .json file into
the full list of paths addressable within it.

Also allows converting to like xml-xpath-like strings
and creating GraphVis renderings of the json structure.

<del>One caveat is if there are empty arrays you will have to

append you own `?` to the `[]` to make them optional.</del>
newer  versions figure it out in most cases